How does an Artificer replace a homunculus servant that dies?
I have a player with a Battle Smith that has both a homunculus servant and a steel defender.
The steel defender spells out pretty clearly what is required if it dies.

If it has died within the last hour, you can use your smith’s tools as an action to revive it, provided you are within 5 feet of it and you expend a spell slot of 1st level or higher. The steel defender returns to life after 1 minute with all its hit points restored.


At the end of a long rest, you can create a new steel defender if you have smith’s tools with you.

The homunculus servant can be repaired using mending, but only if it's still alive. If it dies, it disappears, leaving the "heart" behind.

The homunculus regains 2d6 hit points if the mending spell is cast on it. If you or the homunculus dies, it vanishes, leaving its heart in its space.

Assuming you would just need to infuse it again, this can be done whenever you finish a long rest, and presumably requires

A gem or crystal worth at least 100 gp

But if you hadn't used an infusion yet since your last long rest, could you infuse it immediately? I also don't see the action requirement (sigh...).
Any ideas?

An artificer can replace a Homunculus Servant at the end of a long rest.
As detailed in Infusing an Item, an artificer can infuse a number of items at the end of a long rest.

Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch a non-magical object and imbue it with one of your artificer infusions, turning it into a magic item.

Later, it is specified that you can infuse more than one object.

You can infuse more than one nonmagical object at the end of a long rest...

While, in general,

Your infusion remains in an item indefinitely...

The infusion entry for Homunculus Servant specifies that

If you or the homunculus dies, it vanishes, leaving its heart in its space.

So, an artificer must wait until the end of the next long rest to replace a slain Homunculus Servant.
Infusing items, like preparing spells, requires no action and RAW must be done upon completion of a long rest. Any attempts to forego or delay the act of infusing enters into DM fiat territory.

Pay attention that preparing spells, at least for wizards, take some time: "Preparing a new list of wizard spells requires time spent studying your spellbook and memorizing the incantations and gestures you must make to cast the spell: at least 1 minute per spell level for each spell on your list."

I appreciate the answer, but it's missing the answer to the last question.

I suspect the key part of the answer is an understanding of finish a long rest is not like, any time after wake up, rather [immediately after] you finish a long rest or even, [just before] you finish a long rest.
